# Why is the PLAYFAB_SHARED database no longer available?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I don't have much experience with Snowflake and Playfab, but this is what happened.

Connected Playfab and Snowflake to get the Playfab data into the Snowflake console.
Everything was working good, I created an additional database, created a schema in it and then I got the error on PLAYFAB_SHARED database.

Not sure if what I did was related to it, but this is the current error for the PLAYFAB_SHARED database:

*SQL compilation error: Shared database is no longer available for use. It will need to be re-created if and when the publisher makes it available again.*

Is this something that commonly occurs and how do I fix it?

Can I just run  CREATE DATABASE playfab_shared FROM SHARE xxx.playfab_share without the fear of losing data? I'm guessing that all the data is still stored in Playfab and Snowflake is making it's own copy and storing it into a database.

I can write additional info if necessary. Thank you in advance.
Domagoj

Comment: Whoever owns the shared database likely made some changes and forgot to re-share with you. You should contact them to make it available again.

Answer (score 0):

This error message may have been from a share no longer being available. [Via docs linked here.](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-provider.html#removing-accounts-from-a-share)

If you have access to administrate the share, you should be able to add the account that is having this issue to the Playfab.

1. Does Playfab still show up when you run:

> show shares;

2. See [how to manage reader accounts](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/user-guide/data-sharing-reader-create.html)- you should be able to re-apply permissions to the existing database.

If this is not expected, take note of the query id in QUERY_HISTORY and please contact Snowflake Support for further investigation.